# How to increase gas limit ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain

I am facing this error :

> Error: exceeds block gas limit

When i run below command it returns 5000.

```
web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
```

so as per someone's suggestion 21000 gasLimit is needed to initiate a transaction so i tried to increase it using below command.

```
sudo geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --networkid=15 --targetgaslimit=47123880
```

but after above command execution also gasLimit is still same as 5000.

My purpose is to increase gas limit.

Thanks.

Comment: What gas limit did you set in your genesis?

Comment: "gasLimit": "0x8000000"..but i found in somebody answer that you should not change in genesis once initialize it so trying changing using targetgaslimit.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the gas limit you have to mine with a node with a target gas limit above the one on the network. Each block you mine will increase the limit a little.

Comment: ''Each block you mine will increase the limit a little'' but not increasing..that is the question..why?